# getting this error in ie11: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference

Tags: internet-explorer-11

```js
function run(event) {
console.log(document.getElementById("user").label);
var lable=event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
    if(lable == 'user'){
      document.getElementById("copy").value = "user";
    } else if (lable == 'warehouse') {
     document.getElementById("copy").value = "warehouse";
    } else if (lable == 'dollhouse') {
     document.getElementById("copy").value = "dollhouse";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
<select name="sel" id="sel" onchange="run(event)">
<option selected disabled>Wybierz...</option>
  <optgroup id="user" value="user" label="user">
    <option value="1">michal</option>
    <option value="2">mateusz</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="warehouse" value="warehouse" label="warehouse">
    <option value="1">kosz</option>
    <option value="2">zaginione</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="dollhouse" value="dollhouse" label="dollhouse">
    <option value="1">muiy</option>
    <option value="2">goey</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</form>
<input type="text" name="copy" id="copy">
```

Need helping getting this to work in IE11, works fine in chrome. Getting 'Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference'

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

may this will help or for further you can check this Question and Answers.
[SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124574/script5007-unable-to-get-property-value-of-undefined-or-null-reference)